# Get CBPeripheralManager's Subscribed Centrals

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth

When implementing the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` method `-peripheralManager:willRestoreState`, the object in the dictionary passed to the method for key `CBPeripheralManagerRestoredStateServicesKey` Apple's documentation states that

> All the information about a service is restored, including any included services, characteristics, characteristic descriptors, and subscribed centrals.

From the array of `CBMutableServices`that are returned I can loop through the services and in turn loop through each service's characteristics. However I cannot figure out how to access the subscribed centrals, can anyone help?

Below is the general code I've used which assigns values to local variables etc:

```
    - (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    advertisementData = dict[CBPeripheralManagerRestoredStateAdvertisementDataKey];

    NSArray *services = dict[CBPeripheralManagerRestoredStateServicesKey];

    for (CBMutableService *service in services) {

        mainService = service;

        for (CBMutableCharacteristic *charactristic in mainService.characteristics) {

            if ([charactristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:AUTH_UUID]) {

                authCharacteristic = charactristic;

            } else if ([charactristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:CENTRAL_NAME_UUID]) {

                receiveDeviceNameCharacteristic = charactristic;

            }
        }
        // How would I reinstantiate subscribed centrals?
        // subscribedCentrals = ?

        [manager addService:mainService];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the [subscribed centrals](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBMutableCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBMutableCharacteristic/subscribedCentrals) from the `CBMutableCharacteristic` objects -

so, something like -

```
NSMutableSet *centrals=[NSMutableSet new];

for (CBMutableCharacteristic *charactristic in mainService.characteristics) {

        if ([charactristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:AUTH_UUID]) {

            authCharacteristic = charactristic;

        } else if ([charactristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:CENTRAL_NAME_UUID]) {

            receiveDeviceNameCharacteristic = charactristic;

        }
        for (CBCentral *central in characteristic.subscribedCentrals) {
            [centrals addObject:central];
        }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Absolutely no idea how I missed that in the documentation. Naturally, now that I've seen this I can find it straight away! Thanks for your help.